# Pyspark filter results before loading from Postgres (do not load entire table first)

Tags: python, postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I am trying to migrate a large amount of data from an RDS Postgres instance in a VPC to a redshift cluster in the same VPC. I am trying to do this using PySpark and AWS Glue. I only want to migrate the last 6 months of data, however my query seems to be executing a load of the entire table in question, then filter it, which is causing memory failures. Here is the code I have so far:

```
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.context import GlueContext

sc = SparkContext()
sc.setLogLevel('WARN')
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="db", table_name="table")
datasource0.printSchema()

filtered_dyF = Filter.apply(frame = datasource0, f = lambda x: x["scandate"] > "2020-05-31")
print(filtered_dyF.count())
```

Is there any way I can apply that filter on the load query instead? This path currently attempts to `select * from table` and I would like it to instead `select * from table where scandate > "2020-05-31"`

Comment: Try this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50294863/14165730

Comment: @mck unfortunately my data in Postgres is not partitioned, so using a push down predicate will not work

Comment: or can you use jdbc reader of pyspark? you can read a query into a dataframe with jdbc reader

Comment: I have to use an AWS glue connection because my database is in a VPC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using AWS Database Migration Service. Was actually pretty painless

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it using AWS Glue Only.

```
sample_query = f"SELECT f1, f2 FROM short_url_mapping WHERE f4= '{request_id}' AND"
print("sample_query: " + sample_query)

additional_options = {
    "hashpartitions": 5,
    "hashfield": "request_id",
    "enablePartitioningForSampleQuery": True,
    "sampleQuery": sample_query
}

postgres_dynamic_frame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="database_name",
    table_name="table_name",
    additional_options=additional_options
)
```

Your sampleQuery must end with an AND for AWS Glue to append partitioning conditions.

I followed this AWS Documentation
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-pushdown.html

Glue: 4.0, spark:3.3, Python:3